# If I pass an array using pycuda to the GPU and then print it, why does it print zeros?

Tags: python, cuda, pycuda

I'm trying to use pycuda to accelerate my neural net (I know tensorflow is easier to use for GPU acceleration, I just wanted to do it manually first as I am relatively new to neural networks), but whenever I pass an array to the GPU and have each thread print out the value of the array at the threadIdx, it prints zeros even though I set the array values.

I have tried using an extremely simple kernel for testing that just prints the values of a one dimensional array, and I have tried changing the data type to float32.

The basic kernel that I'm using for testing of this issue:

```c
test_mod = SourceModule("""
    __global__ void test(float *a)
    {
        printf("%d: %d\\n", threadIdx.x, a[threadIdx.x]);
    }

    """)
```

The python code I'm using to create the array and initialize the kernel:

```py
a = np.asarray([4,2,1])
a = a.astype(np.float32)
test_module = test_mod.get_function("test")
test_module(cuda.In(a), block=(3, 1, 1))
```

I expect it to print some order of 4, 2, and 1, but each thread prints a 0.

Comment: Is `%d` the right `printf` format specifier to print a `float` quantity?  I don't think so.  I think it is supposed to be `%f` or something like that.

Comment: Thank you so much! This has had me stuck for forever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the print statement within the kernel. The `%d` format specifier is intended for integers. It will not correctly format a floating point value. To fix it, modify the kernel like this:

```
test_mod = SourceModule("""
    __global__ void test(float *a)
    {
        printf("%d: %f\\n", threadIdx.x, a[threadIdx.x]);
    }

    """)
```

[Answer assembled from comments and added as a community wiki entry to try and get the question off the unaswered queue for the CUDA tag].